# Getting values nested in multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I get the response below from a script, and I need to extract board, model, serial number, current and upgrade.

```
Net\Response Object
(
    [unrecognizedWords:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_type:Net\Response:private] => !re
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [board] => true
            [model] => CRD
            [serialnumber] => XXXXXXXX
            [current] => 5.11
            [upgrade] => 5.11
        )

    [_tag:Net\Message:private] => 
)
```

I've multiple combinations such as this:

```
echo unrecognizedWords:protected->attributes:protected->board;
```

However I can not get the values our of the array.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is that what you literally get from the script?  If so, it's not a proper array, it looks more like the output from var_dump().

Comment: @AlanHorrocks Its a `print_r`.

Comment: Thats weird - which kind of Response object it is? Is it part of some kind of public library or is it just your own object?

Comment: Its a response from Pear.

Answer (score 1):

You cann't get any protected or private properties of object (only public). Use public methods (getters) of this object (sure, that it's provided).

Read: [PHP: Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: Its just the response. I can't just extract the values I need?

Comment: You would have to parse the output into a proper array or object before you could make use of it.  Do you have control over what the script returns?  If so, you could make it return a JSON encoded string, which can be easily made into an object.

Comment: @Borsn, what library do you use to get this response?